# How to save custom objects into preferences in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a global object that store 2 custom class objects, something like this:

```
 /////// Separated object file ////////

    object ApplicationData {
    var profiledata:ProfileData = ProfileData(null)
    var OVOlists = ArrayList<OVOList>()
}
/////// Separated  class file ////////

 class OVOList (
    private var OVOIcon: Int,
    private var OVOName: String?,
    private var OVOPlace: String?,
    private var OVOstatus: Int
) :Parcelable {
    private var Humidity:String? =""
    private var Temperature:String? = ""
    private var PH:String? =""
    private var WaterLvl :String? = ""

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readValue(Int::class.java.classLoader) as Int,
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readValue(Int::class.java.classLoader) as Int
    ) {
        Humidity = parcel.readString()
        Temperature = parcel.readString()
        PH = parcel.readString()
        WaterLvl = parcel.readString()
    } ... + setters , getters and parcel lines

/////// separated class file ////////
class ProfileData(private var email:String?):Parcelable {
    private var token:String? =""
    private var profile_image: String? =""
    private var profile_image_path:String? = ""
    private var nombre:String? = ""
    private var uid:String? = ""

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
    ) {
        token=parcel.readString()
        profile_image = parcel.readString()
        profile_image_path = parcel.readString()
        nombre = parcel.readString()
        uid=parcel.readString()
    } ... + setters,getters and parcel lines
```

The classes are parcelable, because i was moving some information via bundles, but now im using this global object so there is no need to keep them like that.
But the question is how to store the whole object into memory, i have try the Gson/preferences aproach but i cannot make it work :(, it doesnt store the object, maybe its because it has 2 custom class objects inside, i dont think the parcelable attribute should affect. I made something like this:

```
//write//
mprefs.edit().putString("MyappData",gson.toJson(ApplicationData)).apply()
//read//
String json = mprefs.getString("MyappData", "")
val obj = gson.fromJson(json, ApplicationData::java.class)
ApplicationData.profiledata = obj.profiledata
ApplicationData.OVOlists = obj.OVOlists
```

It seems that its failing in the writing part , any ideas what to do?

Comment: I've seen you make a couple of posts now about storing state in a singleton object, and now this - I'd *really* recommend you read this guide about modern app architecture: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture There's a lot in there, but learning to do things the "right" way from the beginning will save you a lot of trouble. I feel like you're already running into issues trying to cram everything into the `SharedPreferences`/`Bundle` way of doing things, and it's only going to get more complicated. Nowadays we can easily share and store state with `ViewModel`s and *repositories*

Comment: If you want to *store* your data, you might want to use the Kotlin `serialization` library: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serialization-guide.md You can think of it like Gson, but designed around Kotlin with a lot of "just works" behaviour. But your problem here might be that `ApplicationData` is an `object` not a `class`, and I'm not sure how Gson would handle that. The error message should give you some idea of why it's failing, but you might need to create an actual class here, and have a `val` holding an instance of it

Answer (score 1):

You can save them as Strings (json format ) and the covert to Object ,as you are doing , I think you should use data classes and use  @Parcelize and avoid using too much code

Comment: Yep, that should do it, the other way would be to use Serializable and write custom methods to turn custom object into a string (or other type) and to turn that string (or any other type) into your custom object

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all your help, i made this work with Gson, i created inside the object a function that stores and retrieves the data from/to pref. i just pass the context to it, i think was not working properly because of the parcelable part inside the classes. The final object is this:

```
object ApplicationData {
var profiledata:ProfileData = ProfileData(null)
var OVOlists = ArrayList<OVOList>()

fun save(context: Context){
    val sharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences("OVO_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val prefsEditor = sharedPreference.edit()
    val gson = Gson()
    val json = gson.toJson(ApplicationData)
    prefsEditor.putString("AppData", json)
    Log.e("saving in preferences",json)
    prefsEditor.apply()
}
fun retrieveData(context: Context):Boolean{
    val sharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences("OVO_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val gson = Gson()
    val json = sharedPreference.getString("AppData", "")
    val obj = gson.fromJson(json, ApplicationData::class.java)
    if(obj!=null){
        profiledata = obj.profiledata
        OVOlists = obj.OVOlists
        //Log.e("retrieve info",obj.OVOlists[0].getOVOName()!!)
        return true
    }else{
        return false }
}
```

The two custom classes now are regular and normal classes, with setters and getters. So the main object can save its own data calling ApplicationData.save(context)